# When do I give notice to my employer if offered a job while on maternity leave?

Tags: job-offer, parental-leave

I wasn't actively looking for a job while on leave, but I was alerted to an opportunity at a company worth better benefits and they offered me the job. I'm on maternity leave and am due to return to work in about a week.
The new job knows of my situation and knows that if my current employer requires me to pay back the medical premiums, that I can't afford that and they are willing to wait until the waiting period for that is over. I need to find out if they would for sure require me to pay back the premiums, how much it would be if that's the case and what the date would be if I return for the time period required so as not to incur the cost (I simply can't afford to absorb it).
Do I go ahead and tell my boss now or wait until I return? Do I talk confidentially to my hr dept but not tell my boss until I have the info and can give appropriate notice?

Comment: "I need to find out if they would for sure require me to pay back the premiums". We can't help you answer this; you need to get this information from your company. Whoever you talk to there works for the company, HR included, and they won't necessarily keep confidential your intention to resign if you tell them. Congratulations on the new job.

Comment: HR is there to protect your company, not you--at least not except insofar as doing so protects your company, which doesn't appear to be the case here. In particular they will not collude with you to help you keep secrets from your boss on this sort of thing. Also if you're using your real name here, you might be exposing yourself to some risk by posting your situation on the web.

Comment: Can you ask if your new Job would take the medical premiums?

Comment: Asking the answers to these questions is going to require some incredibly delicate enquiries.  But surely all this information concerning your liabilities is spelled out in your contract.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like you should look to either your employment contract, an attorney, or to your HR department to have your question answered.

If you don't have a piece of paper that you've signed / been given as a result of your employment explicitly outlining under what conditions you would have to pay this back for, I'm inclined to think that you won't be obligated.

Then again, it's not really my area.

If you don't have anything that specifies you must pay it back, ask the HR department for a list of employee policies. You may be able to find it along with other policies, and this allows you to keep your request vague.

If that doesn't work, you may have to explicitly ask whether employees are required to reimburse these payments under any scenario. Don't be specific about why you're asking.

Before doing so, it may benefit you to consult an attorney to see if there are any actual laws stating that you must pay this back or whether they can require you to pay it back or not.

**Additionally:** Change your display name on Stack Exchange. If you're worried about your company knowing that you intend to leave, you do not want your actual name associated with a question like this (Just to be safe).