# How/when to tell employer you're not coming back after maternity leave?

Tags: parental-leave

My wife is pregnant with our first child. She is currently working full-time and gets her insurance through her employer (which we need to pay for the pregnancy). The employer also offers 3-months maternity leave (although we are not sure if the actual 'pay' benefits are through short-term disability paid by an insurance company or if the company itself kicks in).

As is somewhat common, we are already planning on her not returning to the employer at the end of the 3-months. However, naturally we would like to maintain her health insurance during maternity leave period as well as the 'pay'.

- How and when should she let her employer know?
- Would she lose any of the benefits if she told the employer in advance?
- Would it be unfair/cold if she waited till the last day of her maternity leave?

This question is different than the related answers because it explicitly gets at the **timing** of when to inform the current employer as opposed to how maternity leave effects future employment.

Comment: See also: "[When do I give notice to my employer if offered a job while on maternity leave?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/83016/when-do-i-give-notice-to-my-employer-if-offered-a-job-while-on-maternity-leave)" and "[What to do when two weeks notice period overlaps with parental leave?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/90270/what-to-do-when-two-weeks-notice-period-overlaps-with-parental-leave)"

Comment: @DavidK For the first duplicate, mkennedy answer seems to touch on this question, but notes that the answer is not specific to the question. The other duplicates are in the right direction, but I feel this situation is explicit enough to merit it's own question.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what portions you think make your question distinct from the others? The only bullet that I think isn't covered in the other questions is that about benefits, and since that is about your company's policy, I'm not sure that's answerable here (though I expect you would lose coverage and should look into [COBRA](https://www.dol.gov/general/topic/health-plans/cobra)).

Comment: "I've decided to leave your company.  I received a better offer from a new startup.  The hours are long and the pay is poor, the working conditions are sometimes a little messy, but I really enjoy the culture and new teaching opportunities it provides.  Plus, the joy on my new colleague's face when I arrive each morning cannot be measured by financial compensation"

Comment: @Steve-O Did you mean to post that comment on this question? I'm not sure how it relates.

Comment: @DavidK this first bullet is not answered because all the other questions relate to how quitting will affect future employment. The second bullet could be answered with information on Cobra or FMLA like you mentioned. The third bullet, however, is addressed [in this post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/90270/what-to-do-when-two-weeks-notice-period-overlaps-with-parental-leave)

Comment: I've left a company while near the end of a short term disability. You just wait until the normal time period for giving notice would be. It is a myth that 2-weeks is the amount of time one is "required" to give. In most instances 2 days in plenty of "notice" for leaving. However, if schedules are prepared you should recognize this and give notice before the schedule including the last day of employment in made. Personally, I give 2-weeks for almost all positions I've resigned from. The only time that I didn't is when the environment was toxic or I simply could not.

Comment: @DavidK I think it's supposed to be tongue-in-cheek, the "new startup" being the baby :)

Comment: @whrrgarbl Oohhhh, yeah, that went *completely* over my head